# env: bash: No such file or directory on OSX

Tags: bash, macos, zsh

I am using OSX terminal to run this command:

```
bash -l -c "! [[ -x '/path/to/example.sh' ]] && chmod +x '/path/to/example.sh'; exit 0"
```

/path/to/example.sh exists. Yet I am receiving the error:

> env: bash: No such file or directory

I tried to run this command instead to test if bash is working:

```
bash
```

Which gives:

```
The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
```

I think this confirms bash is working. What next?

Comment: My guess is that there's something in one of your bash login scripts (which the `-l` option tells bash to run) that's causing it. Try removing the `-l` option to see if that removes the message, and also try `bash -l -c true` to see if it's still there even with a trivial command.

Comment: @GordonDavisson `bash -l -c true` gives me the same error, and the error goes away when I remove the -l flag as you predicted. Unfortunately a tool in my build chain is generating these commands so I can't remove the -l in that context. What are bash login scripts and where might I find them on my system? Thanks

Comment: Look in your home directory for any of the files `.bash_profile`, `.bash_login`, or `.profile` (note that the `.` at the beginning of the name makes them normally invisible -- you'll need to use something like `ls -A` to show them). But also, since this is being run by some constrained build tool, it might have to do with how that's running the command. Try `/bin/bash -l -c true` and see if *that* removes the error.

Comment: AFAIK MacOS ships with some terribly (20 years) outdated gnu tools, including bash 3.2 or such. Maybe Apple dropped support for bash completely by now. I always use [homebrew](https://brew.sh) to install all tools I need in recent versions.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thanks I found that removing these lines from my `.profile` resolved the issue `export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:\$PATH"
eval "\$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH="env: bash: No such file or directory
/bin/bash: gem: command not found/bin:\$PATH"` I think these lines are related to RubyGems

Comment: @ToxicTom That looks like garbled commands for setting up a Ruby environment. I'm not familiar with Ruby, so I don't know the correct setup commands, but you should probably look them up and re-add them correctly (unless there's already a non-garbled version in your .profile).

Comment: Notice that the error message comes from `env`. Nothing that you typed includes `env`.

Comment: Why are you using the `-l` option to `bash`? You don't need a login shell in order to  execute that command. In fact, I don't see why you even need `bash -c`, just type the command normally.

Comment: @Robert Apple hasn't removed bash. They changed the default login shell, but bash 3.2 is still there and works fine. They're not upgrading because the license changed from GPL2 to GPL3.

Comment: And you don't need the test for `-x`, or the `exit 0`, just `chmod +x '/path/to/example.sh'`

Comment: @ToxicTom, that's configuration installed by `rbenv`, a tool that helps you set up and manage personal Ruby execution environments.  Although gems play in that arena, rbenv is not specifically about gems.

Comment: The option `-l` tells bash to run as a **login** shell. Now have a look at the bash man page, in particular to the section titled _INVOCATION_. It describes what files are processed by a login shell. Another quick way to locate the source of such errors is to do a `bash -lx -c true`. The _x_ will generate a trace and show you the error in its context.